# This ANE does not support desktop(mac), apple ios device platform

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-native-extensions

I am trying to implement the login with facebook,twitter etc to my game. I am using flash builder 4.7 and sdk 3.8 on mac. while using the Goviral ane extention it shows some error like 
"This ANE dose not support desktop(mac),apple ios device platform". is this happening because of OSX support or ane support or anything else please suggest me solution for it.
Thanx in advance

Comment: what is ANE ? What are you talking about?

Comment: Goviral.ane. Thats Adobe Native extension(ANE)

Comment: Is the error when compiling or when running the app?

Comment: showing when I am putting the file in action build path. properties/AcionBuild Path/Native extension/Add Ane. After adding the file it shows error just below the file path.

Comment: It seems you didn't include the exact error, so I'm guessing the problem is that the native extension (ANE) is not compiled for the target platform you are compiling your air/swf. Please include the exact error.

Comment: exact error is the title for this question. "This ANE does not support desktop(mac),apple ios platform".

Comment: I have the same error when trying to use ratebox.